# Calculating Boundingbox / Missing Points of a Cube / Cuboid

Tags: c++, c, math, vector, 3d

[image]

At the moment i am trying to **calculate the Points of a rectangle / square** depending on the situation (In 3D space every point is a 3D Vector).

My problem is as I am not a genius at maths stuff. I got it working just fine for either situation.

Given Points are 0 and 6 are calculated Origin + min and origin + max. The origin is not always on the ground it can also be elevated. The reason why that is is unknown to me.

For a cube:
Get the point between 0 and 2 referred as D and rotate the Vector D->0 by 90° and -90° Get the Height between 6 and 2 apply them to all points and you've reached all Points for a cube.

For a cuboid:
I assumed that Vector 6->2 is the same as 6->5 thusfore calculating all same principle as before get Height by looking at the z-axis of 6->2 then applying them at the given points 6, 0 and the calculated points 4 and 2.

Both methods work in itself but what I wnated to ask was if anyone knows a method that either allows to combine getting those points in an easier / faster way than calculating all points one by one as well as a method that does work regardless of the shape of the resulting box (works for cuboid as well as cube).

Thanks in advance for anyone who's willing to spare some time on this matter.
Regards.

further visualisation of what i want to achieve. Orange = Origin + min and Blue = Origin + max.
Origin is a point in worldspace min and max are both 3D Vector which define Points of the box.[image: Ingame screenshot.]

```
Vector* Vector::CreateBoundingBox(const Vector& bb_min, const Vector& bb_max) const {
    static Vector retVertices[8];
    Vector vecInvmin;
    float fHeight;
    vecInvmin = bb_min * -1;

    retVertices[0] = *this + bb_min;
    retVertices[1] = *this + bb_min.RotateOnZ(90);
    retVertices[2] = *this + vecInvmin;
    retVertices[3] = *this + vecInvmin.RotateOnZ(90);

    fHeight = (*this + bb_max).Z - retVertices[6].Z - retVertices[2].Z;
    memcpy(&retVertices[4], &retVertices[0], sizeof(Vector) * 4);
    for (__int32 i = 4; i < 8; i++) {
        retVertices[i].Z += fHeight;
    }
    return retVertices;
}
```

Comment: You only have points 0 and 6?  I assume the sides of the cube align with the X Y and Z axes?  (Otherwise there is more than one cube that fits.)

Comment: Consider the similar problem, but in 2D.  You have the bottom-left corner and the top-right corner of a rectangle.  Find the other corners.  Does that help?

Comment: Well as said the resulting geometry can either be a cube or a cuboid so I might fail to understand your Point. Also going away from the thrid dimension kinda makes u lose the information that u can get the points 2 and 4 by calculating the difference of the z-axis of 6 and 0. => height + 0 = 4 and 6 - height = 2

Comment: Why? I am writing it in c++ so if someone provides a code example I'd much rather have it in c/c++

Comment: Added the function which calculates the correct Points for a Cube as an example but as described the problem is a cuboid doesn't have a right angle between the diagonals obviously this method is bound to fail that object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Vector* Vector::CreateBoundingBox(Vector bb_min, Vector bb_max, const Vector& Rotation) const {
    static Vector retVertices[8];
    retVertices[0] = bb_min;
    retVertices[1] = Vector(bb_max.X, bb_min.Y, bb_min.Z);
    retVertices[2] = Vector(bb_max.X, bb_max.Y, bb_min.Z);
    retVertices[3] = Vector(bb_min.X, bb_max.Y, bb_min.Z);
    retVertices[4] = Vector(bb_min.X, bb_min.Y, bb_max.Z);
    retVertices[5] = Vector(bb_max.X, bb_min.Y, bb_max.Z);
    retVertices[6] = bb_max;
    retVertices[7] = Vector(bb_min.X, bb_max.Y, bb_max.Z);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        retVertices[i].RotateXYZ(Rotation);
        retVertices[i] += *this;
    }

    return retVertices;
}
```

The final Source I went with. Actually not really anything to calculate I'm just retarded. Maybe someone needs this if doing something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tested code for Bounding Box calculation.

```
BoundingBox::BoundingBox()
{
    MaxEdge = Vector3(-999.0);
    MinEdge = Vector3(999.0);
}
void BoundingBox::addPointsToCalculateBoundingBox(Vector3 point)
{
    if (point.x > MaxEdge.x)
        MaxEdge.x = point.x;
    if (point.y > MaxEdge.y)
        MaxEdge.y = point.y;
    if (point.z > MaxEdge.z)
        MaxEdge.z = point.z;

    if (point.x < MinEdge.x)
        MinEdge.x = point.x;
    if (point.y < MinEdge.y)
        MinEdge.y = point.y;
    if (point.z < MinEdge.z)
        MinEdge.z = point.z;
}
```

Comment: Not really what I've been looking for as in the screenshot shown above the bounding box is per the definition in this game is a box surrounding an entity. In this case the stoneblock.

Answer (score 0):

Variation on [@codetiger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39303800/2410359) fine answer to avoid magic numbers `-999.0, 999.0`.

By reversing the `>` test to `! <=`, the same results occur with valued numbers.  Yet when `MaxEdge.x` is a NaN, the initial value, `!(point.x <= MaxEdge.x)` is true and `MaxEdge.x` is assigned the first time `addPointsToCalculateBoundingBox()` is called.  Side benefit, should code attempt to use `MaxEdge.x` before calling `addPointsToCalculateBoundingBox()`, it will have the "value" of `NaN`. likely triggering a problem sooner than if it had the value of `-999.0`.

```
BoundingBox::BoundingBox() {
    // Initialize to Not-A-Number
    MaxEdge = Vector3(0.0/0.0);
    MinEdge = Vector3(0.0/0.0);
}

void BoundingBox::addPointsToCalculateBoundingBox(Vector3 point)
{
    if (!(point.x <= MaxEdge.x)) MaxEdge.x = point.x;
    if (!(point.y <= MaxEdge.y)) MaxEdge.y = point.y;
    if (!(point.z <= MaxEdge.z)) MaxEdge.z = point.z;

    if (!(point.x >= MinEdge.x)) MinEdge.x = point.x;
    if (!(point.y >= MinEdge.y)) MinEdge.y = point.y;
    if (!(point.z >= MinEdge.z)) MinEdge.z = point.z;
}
```

Comment: Well basically if I am not mistaken this algorithm is a simplistic way to check if the a given Point is inside the Bounding Box. But that is not what i need i need a function which returns 8 Points and takes in min and max vector